# Using selenium with Open Layers

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, openlayers

It is not possible to automate the clicks on the map elements which are svg nodes (they do not have specific x-paths which selenium relies on).We tried clicking on features which also fails as it is also set as a svg element. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: can you use CSS selectors instead?

Comment: each svg does not have its own unique css class specified by open layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for this (at least for point feature types). It is done using issuing a request to the DB to get the feature coordinates and then using the following method to get the pixel values for the x,y coordinates for the points.

```
OpenLayers.getPixelFromLonLat()
```

After that the Open Layers click controller is used to issue a request to the given pixel. It works on all window sizes as well.